# Съехала вёрстка в очереди проверок и слетели несколько переводов

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, очередь-проверок

[В очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) кнопка "Проверка на Мета" живет своей жизнью. Также слетел её перевод и нескольких других элементов:

> [image: проверки]

Comment: уже зарепортили на MSE про съехало: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322008/348096

Comment: @AK и уже типо пофиксили. Правда с переводами, как обычно, задержка.

Comment: Кстати, кнопка уже внизу. Она там навсегда (такая новая задумка?) или опять что-то слетело?

Comment: Оригинальная ссылка тоже внизу была насколько я помню. А теперь их сделали кнопочками. При 10к+ репы ещё [кнопка "Инструменты" есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5ZXO.png) в правом верхнем углу.

Comment: Заодно это починили https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319317/260198

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322030/new-strings-are-not-on-transifex

Comment: @m0sa thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- [Recent reviews](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11184)
- [Meta reviews](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11185)
- [Choose a task to get started](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11182)

Ожидайте на сайте не раньше понедельника.

Ну а вёрстку поправили на MSE: [Link to meta queues broken on wide screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322008/339911)