# Слетел перевод в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, мета

Слетел перевод в [очереди проверок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review), причем как на Мета, так и на основном ruSO:

> [image: очереди]

Comment: Да, это всё с той же поры, когда [обновили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8499/213987) страницу очередей.

Comment: @AK если честно, не заглядывал, я как-то думал что уже давно решилась проблема и это новая вылезла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил перевод свежедобавленной фразы:

- [Help improve it by **evaluating new posts**, **voting to close or reopen questions**, or **reviewing suggested edits**.](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11189)

  Помогите улучшить его **оценкой новых сообщений**, **голосованием за закрытие или повторное открытие вопросов** или **рецензированием предлагаемых правок**.